# How to schedule a thread in C++11?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

With the below code, I would like to place(push_back) the threads in a vector and launch the thread after every pop operation from vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>


int main() {
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        workers.push_back(std::thread([](){
                std::cout << "Hi from thread\n";
            }));
    }

    std::cout << "Hi  from main!\n";
    std::for_each(workers.begin(), workers.end(), [](std::thread &th){
        th.join();
    });
    return 0;
}
```

But `push_back()` instruction does not actually convey that we are storing threads to launch it later. Because calling a constructor of `class std::thread` immediately launches  thread.

In java, launch of thread can happen by placing in Queue(say) and dequeue it something like this:

```
-> searchQueue.enqueue( new SearchTask( record, this ) );

-> return searchQueue.size () > 0 ? (Runnable) searchQueue.removeFirst () : null ;
```

Because in java, thread gets launched after you invoke `start()` method of `class Thread`.

So, How do i perform similar operation in C++11?

Comment: What's the point of the exercise? Why can't you just push the thread onto the vector when you are ready to launch it? Why do you feel you need this two-step dance?

Comment: This violates the idea of a std::thread itself; it is not a "zombie" object, it is meant to look and act like a literal thread of execution. I guess you could wrap it in an std::unique_ptr and instantiate it later. But that is utterly pointless, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can store non-running threads plus the functions they will later run together:

```
typedef std::pair<std::thread, std::function<void()>> ThreadAndFunction;

std::vector<ThreadAndFunction> workers;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    ThreadAndFunction tf;
    workers.emplace_back(std::thread(), [](){
            std::cout << "Hi from thread\n";
        });
}
```

Then later, activate the threads using the functions:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    workers[i].first = std::thread(workers[i].second);
}
```

However, I don't think you're gaining much here.  You could just store the functions without the empty threads at first, and create a vector of threads later.